# How to test lookup?

Tags: 2010, workflow, lookup-column, testing

When creating a workflow, is there any way to test the look up values? For instance, I have a 4-level look up which finds the manager of a user who is entered on the form. I'd like to be able to see what value comes out for a given user, to make sure the lookup was creating correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the workflow, assuming you're using SharePoint Designer, you can store the information in a variable and output it to the workflow history or email yourself the value.  That's how I test data I'm not entirely sure how it will come back or what the format of it will be.

Comment: what a old-school way of working ! Microsoft should add features to SPD to have a "debug" mode for workflows... at least a technical log or even a "console" to help debugging. I'm even dreaming something of the availability of a step-by-step debugger, like VS. Oh no! I'm awake... let's add a tone of variable, and history log